# Not readable outputs while running pyodbc hive connection with Python 3.7.0 and pyodbc-4.0.28

Tags: python-3.x, hive, pyodbc, unixodbc

I am running some code in python using pyodbc by making a connection with Hive. Whenever; I get any error on the console, it is not understandable. Following is an output :

```
conn=pyodbc.connect("DSN=hive_db", autocommit=True) 
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', '[28000] 䡛牯潴睮牯獫孝桔楲瑦硅整獮潩嵮⠠⤲䔠牲牯漠捣牵摥搠牵湩\u2067畡桴湥楴慣楴湯.ᙸƛ\x00\x00騀샹翾\x00\x02\x00罙\x00鴠샹翾\x00ᙸƛ\x00\x00궈磐罙\x00鞰蒀罙\x00궈磐罙\x00馠샹翾 (2) (SQLDriverConnect)
```

What can be the possible reason for such an output? How can we convert it to have a readable output?

Thanks,

Comment: What version of unixODBC are you using? (You can use `odbcinst -j` to check.)

Comment: Hi, unixODBC version is unixODBC-2.3.4.

Comment: Try upgrading to the latest unixODBC (currently 2.3.7). The 2.3.5 release in particular fixed a lot of bugs.

Comment: Thanks Thompson. Will do that and update my answer here.